# Difference between "hiems" and "hībernum"

Tags: vocabulary, definitions

The two words both translate to "winter" in English.<sup>[1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hiems#Latin),[2](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hibernum#Latin)</sup>

Although information on Wikipedia is sparse, I gather that *hiems* is most commonly used as a noun, while *hibernum* is the noun form of the more common adjective *[hībernī](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hiberni#Latin)* (wintry).

Both forms, however, are shown as nouns. How do they differ in usage? Are they essentially interchangeable synonyms?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you noted (almost correctly), *hibernum* comes from *hibernus, -a, -um* which does mean 'wintry'. Any neuter adjective can be made into a noun by simple use. It's a feature of the language.

However, *hibernum* is rare and not often used. 99% of the time when an author wants to say 'winter', they say *hiems*, if not perhaps some poetical euphemism. *Hibernum*'s importance comes not from meaning winter, but rather from its meaning in the plural as 'winter-quarters for troops". See [Lewis and Short II.B](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=hibernum&la=la#lexicon).