# What is the difference between uti and quare?

Tags: vocabulary, interrogative

Uti and quare seem to have similar meanings, (how? or in what manner?)

Is there a difference between the two words? What situations would they be used in that would differ?

Comment: I didn't vote on this, but I'm guessing the downvotes come from the lack of exposition? Perhaps if you add some background/context/the definitions in question or show that you've read the relevant dictionaries, that might encourage others to post. See e.g. [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/70/difference-between-hiems-and-hībernum).

Answer (score 2):

There certainly is overlap in meaning between *uti* and *quare*, but there are some uses for *uti* which *quare* cannot be used for. *Uti* (or more usual, just *ut*) can be used as a relative adverb with a correlative like *sic* or *tam* or *adeo*.

*Sic celer cucurrit ut Lucia*, "he ran as fast as Lucy". Here *sic* and *ut* are used much like *tam* and *quam*. *Quare*, on the other hand, is rarely used with its correlative *ea re*, and even when it is, it's never used to express a comparative of degree, but only manner. *Ea re celer cucurrit qua re Lucia*, "he ran fast in the manner that Lucy did."